# C# + EntityFramework: Convert multiple group by query to nested JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, linq, entity-framework

I made the following linq statement

**C#**

```
var list = from row in repository.GetAllEntities()
                       group row by new { row.RegionString, row.SubRegionString, row.CountryString } into g
                       select new { g.Key.RegionString, g.Key.SubRegionString, g.Key.CountryString, Count = g.Count() };

return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

That returns

```
[
  {
    "RegionString":"Americas",
    "SubRegionString":"",
    "CountryString":"",
    "Count":2
  },
  {
    "RegionString":"Americas",
    "SubRegionString":"NorthAmerica",
    "CountryString":"Canada",
    "Count":5
  },
  {
    "RegionString":"Americas",
    "SubRegionString":"NorthAmerica",
    "CountryString":"US",
    "Count":3
  },
  {
    "RegionString":"Americas",
    "SubRegionString":"SouthAmerica",
    "CountryString":"Chile",
    "Count":3
  },
  {
    "RegionString":"EMEA",
    "SubRegionString":"AsiaPacific",
    "CountryString":"Australia",
    "Count":2
  },
  {
    "RegionString":"EMEA",
    "SubRegionString":"AsiaPacific",
    "CountryString":"Japan",
    "Count":1
  },
  {
    "RegionString":"EMEA",
    "SubRegionString":"SouthernEurope",
    "CountryString":"Turkey",
    "Count":1
  },
  {
    "RegionString":"EMEA",
    "SubRegionString":"WesternEurope",
    "CountryString":"",
    "Count":1
  }
]
```

But I am trying to make it into this format

```
[{
    name: "Americas",
    children: [
     {
         name: "NorthAmerica",
         children: [{ "name": "Canada", "count": 5 },
                    { "name": "US", "count": 3 }]

     },
     {
         name: "SouthAmerica",
         children: [{ "name": "Chile", "count": 1 }]
     },
    ],
},
{
    name: "EMA",
    children: [
     {
         name: "AsiaPacific",
         children: [{ "name": "Australia", "count": 2 },
                    { "name": "Japan", "count": 1 }]

     },
     {
         name: "SouthernEurope",
         children: [{ "name": "Turkey", "count": 1 }]
     },
    ],
}]
```

How could I modify the statement to get the result I'm looking for? Non linq answers are acceptable too.

**EDIT:** Region is the parent of SubRegion, SubRegion is the parent of Country and Count is the unique number of items that belongs to Country

Comment: can you explain what your trying to do beside the format? ie.  sub region is the children for region string

Comment: Just edited the answer with the hierarchy. Hopefully that is helpful

Comment: you could probably do it with a dictionary of dictionaries i'm trying to make a solution right now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the **linq query** you want (*I've removed the `-String` postfix for readability*):

```
var list =
    from entity in repository.GetAllEntities()
    group entity by entity.Region into regions
    let childrenOfRegions =
        from region in regions
        group region by region.SubRegion into subregions
        let countriesOfSubRegions =
            from subregion in subregions
            group subregion by subregion.Country into countries
            select new { Name = countries.Key }
        select new { Name = subregions.Key, Children = countriesOfSubRegions }
    select new { Name = regions.Key, Children = childrenOfRegions };
```

There is no `Count` in this query, since I don't really understand what you are counting.

What I'm doing here is grouping the rows into Regions and in the last line you can see the
`select new { Name = regions.Key, ... }` part where I'm returning the Regions.
To get the children, you need to group the Regions into SubRegions (*the same way with Regions*). You repeat this all the way down to the Countries and you're done.